# why is Redshift giving me a divide by zero error?

Tags: sql, subquery, amazon-redshift, division, divide-by-zero

I'm aware that there are some pitfalls around floating points in Redshift, but I can't get past this.

I have columns col1 and col2 and want to create a simple division as "calc". col1 and col2 are sometimes zero, so I use where col2 > 0. There are no null values for col1 and col2. This works fine:

```
select col1*1.0/col2 as calc
from t1
where col1 > 0 and col2 > 0
```

But if I use any value in the where clause for calc, I get the error:

```
select calc from 
(select col1*1.0/col2 as calc
from t1
where col1 > 0 and col2 > 0) 
where calc < 1 -- error here for any value, gt or lt

SQL Error [500310] [57014]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Divide by zero;
```

I tried a whole bunch of things including different values for calc, cast as decimal or float, but I get the same error. Why?

Comment: Your use of "*1.0" makes me wonder if the data types of col1 and col2 are INTs (or numeric).  Are they floats?

Comment: Yes, they are treated as INTs so "select 1/2" returns 0. "select 1.0/2" returns 0.5.

Comment: Exactly, an implicit cast and as GMB said Redshift is compiling your query in best way it sees to optimize the execution.  In doing this it isn't respecting implicit casting.  You could try explicit casting to force things - "col1::float / col2::float".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redshift probably optimizes the operation tree of the query in a manner that results in the division in the `select` clause being evaluated before the conditions in the `where` clause.

You can work around this with `nullif()`:

```
select calc 
from (
    select col1 * 1.0 / nullif(col2, 0) as calc
    from t1
    where col1 > 0 and col2 > 0
) 
where calc < 1
```